# How click innerhtml data if start code td?

Tags: regex, split, web-scraping, innertext, htmlelements

I am want click innerhtml area but when I am using my code then it's totally not working but when I am try web browser contain then message show working well. I think I am mistaken something pls help me.

html code

```
<td class="messageline__box">
    <a class="messageline__link" href="/message/14418316360000000524">
        <span class="messageline__from">

            your billing available
        </span>
        <span class="messageline__subject">

            your well position, adep khan
        </span>
    </a>
</td>
```

My trying code

```
if (webBrowser1.DocumentText.Contains("Confirm your Twitter account"))
        {
            Thread.Sleep(150);


            foreach (HtmlElement el in webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("span"))
            {
                if (el.InnerText == ("your well position"))
                {
                    el.InvokeMember("Click");
                }
            }

            MessageBox.Show("Working Well");


        }
```

Please check & give me idea how I am click with continue my work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to debug your code more carefully. The `span` you need to click has a longer inner text value (`your well position, adep khan`). Thus, you need to use `String.Contains`:

```
if (el.InnerText.Contains("your well position"))
{
     el.InvokeMember("Click");
}
```

Comment: Excellent Help. I am forget this issue but it's now working really fine.